# How to properly state as to why $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^3+2}}{n^4+3n^2+1}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^3+2}}{n^4+3n^2+1}$ converges, because the highest power in the numerator is $n^\frac{3}{2}$ and the highest power in the numerator is $n^4$, so I have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^3+2}}{n^4+3n^2+1} \approx \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^\frac{3}{2}}{n^4}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^\frac{5}{2}}$ and the last series converges by p-series >1, but in an exam setting would that be an appropriate way of going about showing convergence? If it isn't, how would I do this? I tried limit comparison and it came back inconclusive for various other functions. And the integral test appears overkill for this in my opinion, if it fits the criteria. Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: You could try showing each term is lesser that $\dfrac1{n^2}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_{n} = \frac{\sqrt{n^{3}+2}}{n^{4}+3n^{2} + 1}$ and let $b_{n} = \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ for some positive $\alpha$. Consider

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{\sqrt{n^{3}+2}}{n^{4}+3n^{2} + 1}}{\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{\alpha}\sqrt{n^{3}+2}}{n^{4}+3n^{2} + 1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{\alpha}n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{n^{4}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{\alpha}n^{-\frac{5}{2}}$$

If $\alpha = 5/2$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n}/b_{n} = 1$ and by the limit comparison test both $\sum a_{n}$ and $\sum b_{n}$ converge together or diverge together...

Answer (score 3):

- On one hand, the series is strictly increasing.
- On the other hand, $n^3+2\le2n^3$ and $n^4+3n^2+1\ge n^4$, implying $t_n\le\ldots~\Big($I'll let you fill in the dots, and draw the conclusion for yourself$\Big)$.